# Remove padding in google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm wondering why google charts add a blank padding when not specifying the top/right/left axises.

[image]

Select the image and you'll find a huge padding except the bottom which is already filled & that's why, how to remove that?

Specifically, Talking about the right and left paddings.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the url you are using (charts.api.google.com/...) ?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `chartArea` option as follows:

```
options.chartArea = { left: '8%', top: '8%', width: "70%", height: "70%"};
```

More documentation can be viewed here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options

Answer (score 3):

When using the **Google Chart API** you can eliminate the padding. I made an example [Here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chma=0,0,0,0&cht=bvg&chs=250x150&chd=s:Monkeys&chxs=0,ff0000,12,0,lt%7C1,0000ff,10,1,lt).

The relevant parameter is *chma*.

[According to the documentation:](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_chart_margins)

> You can specify the size of the chart's margins, in pixels. Margins are calculated inward from the specified chart size (chs); increasing the margin size does not increase the total chart size, but rather shrinks the chart area, if necessary.

You can try these parameters online in the Chart Playground [HERE](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_playground.html).

HTH!

[image]

**Edit: Warning from Google**

[Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/)

Comment: chma is now deprecated, for a 2012 answer to this question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661456/remove-padding-or-margins-from-google-charts

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as said in [Chart Margins](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_chart_margins) documentation you can set only the **minimum** margin on each side of the chart.

Google adds some unnecessary margin (mostly on top) itself and there is no parameter which can stop this behavior.