# Remove space between Google Charts in a table

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, charts, google-visualization

I have multiple pie charts that are in a table. How can i remove the space between them?

I tried a lot if different options (making the div element smaller, this: [Remove padding or margins from Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661456/remove-padding-or-margins-from-google-charts), or this: [remove space between two td elements in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252512/remove-space-between-two-td-elements-in-a-table)), but nothing worked.

This is my code: JS

```
function drawPieCharts(countChoices, name) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var property in countChoices) {
            if (countChoices.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rows.push([property, countChoices[property]]);
            }
        }


        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
        datatable.addRows(rows);
        var options = {
            title: String(name),
            is3D: 'true',
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(String(name)));
        chart.draw(datatable, options);
    }
```

and the html code

```
</head>
  <body>
    <!--Table and divs that hold the charts-->
    <table width="50%">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="1" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="2" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="3" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="4" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="5" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
        <td><div id="6" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div id="7" style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, recommend assigning the size of the chart in the chart options,
rather than in the container's `style` attribute
and since we're dealing with circles,
also recommend using the same size for height and width (500 x 500)

next, use chart option `chartArea` to stretch the chart to the width of the container.
to do so, you will need to move the `legend` to the top or bottom.

```
  chartArea: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    top: 36,
    right: 12,
    bottom: 12,
    left: 12
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    alignment: 'center'
  },
```

use `chartArea` options `top, right, bottom, left` to leave room on the edges,
for things like the `title`, `legend`, and the "slice highlight" on hover

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function() {
  var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
  datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  datatable.addRows([
    ['A', 10],
    ['B', 10],
    ['C', 10],
    ['D', 10],
  ]);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    drawChart(i);
  }

  function drawChart(index) {
    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        top: 36,
        right: 12,
        bottom: 12,
        left: 12
      },
      title: 'Chart ' + index,
      is3D: 'true',
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        alignment: 'center'
      },
      height: 500,
      width: 500
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(index.toString()));
    chart.draw(datatable, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="1"></div></td>
    <td><div id="2"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="3"></div></td>
    <td><div id="4"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="5"></div></td>
    <td><div id="6"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="7"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you maybe help me with this too?: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250682/sorting-of-google-charts-in-sharepoint/250724

Comment: not sure how to help, what is the sort order you're looking for?

Comment: a manual one. i would like to write something like: sort (A,C,S,U,B)